# Disable a css for part of the content

Tags: html, css, yii-extensions

I am using Yii-bootstrap extension and I am having some styling problem because bootstrap css files affect the main content of the page.

My main content is a map done with OpenLayers so I am having several problems with styles mixing between them. I have tried to do a css file more general, as I have seen they recomend on the web,for applying different styles but as they are two "automatic" libraries is a hard work to try to guess how they work and the classes they use.

Is there any way to disable a css file for a concrete div?

Comment: The problem here is that the `Bootstrap` CSS and the OpenLayers CSS conflict with each other. There is no way of excluding CSS for part of the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a class for that div and reset the values you have changed for general divs.

Comment: found: http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-1-resetting-your-styles-with-css-reset/

Comment: under that page this link i find it usefull, hope it helps;
http://perishablepress.com/a-killer-collection-of-global-css-reset-styles/

Comment: instead of general resetting it, just apply what needs to be reseted to your specific class

Comment: At the end I have done it reseting each style it disturbs the map view.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing that I'm aware of, no.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see is..

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner" >
        Inner Content
    </div> 
</div>
```

You could do something like..

```
.outer{
}

.outer .inner{
/* override the specific styles you need here */
}
```