# Disable css on part of site (not override)

Tags: css

How can I disable a css file for some `<div>`? I use MaterializeCSS framework and I have a specific area on my site where I want to use default browser styles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable a css for part of the content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793568/disable-a-css-for-part-of-the-content)

Comment: It is too much styles to override

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only

Answer (score 1):

Full cross-browser?
If not, give that div a custom class, and then reset children nodes with [`all property`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-all).
Something like:

```css
p {
  color: red
}
.no-style > * {
  all: unset;
}
```

```html
 <div class="some-class">
     <p>custom style</p>
 </div>

<div class="no-style">
  <p>default style</p>
</div>

<p>custom style</p>
```